# printing the name of the extended class(using java) and which also checks whether that class(extended) has an _avi extension or not

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want a program which prints the name of the extended class(using java) and which also checks whether that class(extended) has an _avi extension or not.

Comment: What is the question? It's rather unclear what you're asking help about.